# Purpose of Fermat's Little Theorem

Tags: number-theory

What is the purpose of using Fermat's Little Theorem, and a proof of it?

Comment: Did you try http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem ?

Comment: There are a full 6 proofs on wikipedia.

Comment: What do you mean by "purpose?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Below is what Weil wrote on proofs of Fermat's little theorem, from p. 56 of his *Number theory: An approach through history*. As for its purpose, it helps serve to reveal the  multiplicative structure  of $\rm\:\mathbb Z/p\:,\:$ and problems in $\rm\:\mathbb Z\:$ are often best solved by reducing them to much simpler problems in its finite images $\rm\:\mathbb Z/p\:,\:$ e.g. so-called "local-global" principles. No doubt a search on "Fermat little" will uncover many applications - both here and elsewhere.

[image] 
[image]

Comment: where could i find Leibniz's proof using multinomial theorem ?? can someone summarize thanks

Answer (score 3):

In modular arithmetic e.g. mod m you can reduce big numbers down to numbers between 0 and m.

Fermat's little theorem lets you reduce the exponents (of numbers of the form $b^e$) down to numbers between 0 and $\varphi(m)$ (without knowing anything about the base).

---

For example of the first, $x = 0,1,2$ or $3$ mod 4 so the number $x^2$ must be equal to 0 or 1 mod 4. So $x^2$ is of the form 4k or 4k+1.

For an example of the second, if p is prime $\varphi(p) = p-1$ then  $p^2 = 1$ mod p-1 so $x^{(p^2)} = x$ mod p. I just made that up but you can probably see from it that you can use this for lots of things.

Comment: Surprisingly, Euler's extension of Fermat's Little Theorem plays a crucial role in modern cryptography.

Comment: @lhf: Actually Fermat's little theorem is enough for RSA, and Euler's theorem is not needed. The reason is that given distinct primes $p,q$ and $jk = a(p-1)(q-1)+1$ we have $x^{jk} \equiv (x^{a(p-1)})^{q-1} \cdot x \equiv x \pmod{q}$ (using Fermat's little theorem if $q \nmid x$), and by symmetry $x^{jk} \equiv x \pmod{p}$, and hence $p,q \nmid x^{jk}-x$, and the proof is finished using Euclid's lemma. =)

Answer (score 2):

Fermat's little theorem states that, for a prime $p$:

$$ a^p \equiv a \pmod{p} $$

alternatively:

$$ a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p} $$

The easiest proof that I've seen is as follows:  Consider *any* integer, $g$, that is relatively prime to $p$.  Let $x$ be the product of all of the (distinct) integers $\pmod{p}$.  i.e.:

$$ x = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot 3 \dots (p-1) \pmod{p} $$

Now, multiply each term on the right by $g$:

$$ g^{p-1} x = (g \cdot 1) (g \cdot 2) (g \cdot 3) \dots (g \cdot (p-1)) \pmod{p} $$

Since multiplication is 1-1 and onto, all this does is permute the values involved in the product on the right to give back $x$.  So:

$$ g^{p-1} x = x \pmod{p} $$
$$ g^{p-1} = 1 \pmod{p} $$

One needs to prove multiplication is 1-1 and onto (for $p$ prime), but once that's done, the proof above is (in my opinion) straight forward and simple.

EDIT:  I originally restricted the product, $x$, to be the product of powers of a generator, $g$.  As lhf points out, this can be any number.  I've changed the above to reflect this.

Comment: No need to use a generator. Consider the product of $ax$ for $x=1,\dots,p-1$.

Comment: Wow, that's not "easy" because knowing that there is a generator for the multiplicative group is non-trivial, isn't it?  And if you are gonna jump to group theory, you know that $g^{|G|}=1$ for all $g\in G$ for any group $G$, so you don't really need a generator.

Comment: @lhf, you are absolutely right.  @Thomas, the above proof without the generator condition is now much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

We prove by fermat's little theorem by induction. Firstly, the base case tells us that

$1^{p} \equiv 1$ (mod $p$), which is true.

Assume true for $a=k$, namely that we assume $k^{p} \equiv k $ (mod $p$).

Then for $a = k+1$, we observe that $(k+1)^p - (k^p +1) = pk$ + $p \choose 2$ $k^2$ + $\ldots$ $k^{p-1}$ $p\choose p-1$.

I leave it as an exercise to check that the R.H.S. is divisible by $p$, and so we have the chain of congruences (using the induction hypothesis) that $(k+1)^p \equiv k^p + 1 \equiv k+1 $ (mod $p$). So the statement of fermat's little theorem is true for $a = 1$, $a = k$ and $a = k+1$ and hence is true for all natural numbers $k$.

$\hspace{6in}\blacksquare$

Ben