# Why is $a^{5} \equiv a\pmod 5$ for any positive integer?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic

Why is $a^{5} \equiv a\pmod 5$ for any positive integer?

I feel like it should be obvious, but I just can't see it. Any help appreciated.

Edit: without Fermat's theorem.

Comment: Isn't this a direct application of Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: Fermat's little theorem: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem

Comment: @Deepak Which is usually a hint that the OP doesn't know the theorem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Purpose of Fermat's Little Theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/34040/purpose-of-fermats-little-theorem)

Comment: @Deepak: Thomas got it right, I'd never heard of the theorem before.

Comment: To avoid using the theorem, you can just check it case-by-case. Or else prove the theorem (it is a near-immediate consequence of Lagrange's theorem for the multiplicative group ${\bf Z}_p^*$ of integers not divisible by $p$ modulo $p$).

Comment: @Bob Sorry about that. I provided an elementary solution without using the theorem in an answer below. Other solutions have been given, e.g. using induction. Hope these are helpful.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Point taken, and an alternative solution posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to prove this is to prove it by induction. If $n^5\equiv n\pmod 5$ show that $(n+1)^5\equiv n+1\pmod 5$.

Note that $$(n+1)^5=n^5+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n+1\equiv n^5+1\equiv n+1\pmod5$$

The general theorem people have mentioned in comments, Fermat's Little Theorem, states that if $p$ is prime and $a$ is any number: $a^p\equiv a\pmod p$.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know you can prove the theorem like that (by induction). That's neat. Also pretty obvious in hindsight. But still neat.

Comment: Only works for positive $n$. Can prove for negative in one step, though, from the positives, since $5$ is odd. :)

Comment: This is nice, you just have to know that $\binom{p}{k}$ is divisible by $p$ for all $0<k<p$.

Comment: I was trying to keep it absolutely minimal to prove just for the case $5$, but yes, the general Fermat can be proved that way, @TravisJ. My favorite way to prove FLT is combinatorial - counting the number of ways of painting $p$ beads in a circle with $n$ colors. There are $n$ solid necklaces, and then the rest of the colorings can be grouped in sets of $p$ by rotation.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Was there modular arithmetic that let you solve the congruence you listed under "note that"?

Comment: You mean other than that $10\equiv 5\equiv 0\pmod 5$? @Bob

Comment: I'm just not seeing how this played out:  $$n^5+5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n+1\equiv n^5+1\equiv n+1\pmod5$$ Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: @Bob Note that all multiples of $5$ immediately reduce to $0$ modulo $5$.

Comment: The second part, $n^5+1\equiv n+1$ is by the induction hypothesis- we assumed $n^5\equiv n$. @Bob

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't realize you could do that. I mean I knew $10\equiv5\equiv0 \pmod 5$ was true, but I didn't know you could just remove them (I guess it's called reducing).

Comment: Well, if $a\equiv b$ then $a+c\equiv b+c$. So $5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n\equiv 0\pmod{5}$ and therefore adding to $n^5+1+(5n^4+10n^3+10n^2+5n)\equiv n^5+1\pmod 5$. I don't think anybody calls that "reducing," @Bob

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Lots of people call it exactly that. Just Google. For instance,https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&ei=7ukxVaD2No7VuQSdwYCoBg&url=http://m.youtube.com/watch%3Fv%3DSO6l6sDwEFg&ved=0CCIQtwIwAQ&usg=AFQjCNGcYUdyv1GOyh4hY05tWmxR3v7Tkw&sig2=MX3mTWP5TQICXMg3XTSmIg

Answer (score 4):

OK, *without* using Fermat's Little Theorem (a far more general and elegant result), here's another easy workaround.

Any integer $a$ can be exactly one of $0, 1, 2, -2, -1 \pmod 5$.

Take the fifth powers of each of those and see them reduce back to the original residue in each case.

Answer (score 3):

Consider $$a(a-1)(a-2)(a-3)(a-4)=a(a^4-10a^3+35a^2-50a+24).$$ Taken mod $5$ this becomes
$$a(a^4-1).$$and so $a^5-a \equiv 0 \mod 5$, or $a^5 \equiv a \mod 5$ as required.

Answer (score 2):

Note $\ a(a^4\!-1\!)\, =\, a(a^2-1)\overbrace{(a^2+1)}^{\Large \color{#0a0}{a^2-4}\,+\,\color{#c00}5} = \!\!\!\underbrace{a(a^2-1)(\color{#0a0}{a^2-4})}_{\large\color{blue}{ (a-2)(a-1)a(a+1)(a+2)}}\!\!\!\! + \color{#c00}5\,a(a^2-1)$

$\color{#c00}5\,$ divides both summands, the first because $\,\color{#c00}5\,$ divides one of $\,\rm\color{#c00}5\,\  \color{blue}{\rm  consecutive\ integers}$.

Answer (score 0):

As others said, it's Fermat's little theorem.  One way to verify it in this particular case is to note that 
$$a^5 - a = a (a - 1)(a+1)(a^2 + 1)$$
If $a \equiv 0, 1$ or $4 \mod 5$, one of the first three factors is $0 \mod 5$.
The other two possibilities are $a \equiv 2$ or $3 \mod 5$, in which case 
$a^2 + 1 \equiv 4 + 1 \equiv 0 \mod 5$.  So in each case, $a^5 \equiv a \mod 5$.

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution is the following:

Consider the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_{p}^{\ast}$ of non-zero elements $\mod p$.  This group has $p-1$ elements.  Then for any element in the group, there is a cyclic subgroup $\langle g\rangle$.  The order of this group is the order of $g$ which divides $p-1$, say the order is $k$ and $ak=p-1$.  This means that $g^{p-1}=g^{ak}=(g^{k})^{a}\equiv 1^{a} \equiv 1 \mod p$.  Multiplying again by $g$ you have that $g^{p}\equiv g \mod p$.  That works for all the non-zero elements.  It is obvious for the 0.

Comment: This is essentially a proof of Fermat's little theorem.  It works for any prime $p$ (of which 5 is one example).